# How To Use A Variable As A URL Parameter With PAW API Tool For Mac?

Tags: paw-app

This question relates to the [PAW API tool available for Mac](https://paw.cloud), version 3.1.5.

I know that I can use variables in the request URL to change things such as protocol, host, etc. Also that they may be used within the text body to change JSON and so on.

Is there a way to also use them in URL parameters? E.g.

http://www.foo.com?bar=yes

where `bar` is a variable that is configured in the Environments view?
[image]

Comment: Basic answer is: **yes!** But you have to be more specific about the technology you are using, what language, what framework...

Comment: Added clarification above. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do so.

1. Configure your variable in the Environment Variables editor
2. In the *URL Params* tab, add a new parameter: choose a name
3. In the value field, right-click and pick Environment > [Your variable]

Alternatively, instead of using the contextual menu, you can use autocompletion to find your variable.

Here's how it should look like:

[image: Configure a variable as a URL query parameter in Paw]

Comment: awesome thanks! I'm starting to really appreciate just how good PAW is.